# jquery checkbox filter with categories

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I was creating a similar filter as in this jsfiddle demo: http://jsfiddle.net/nJUb3/1/

When you check red and yellow in this fiddle example, it shows the flowers which contain both of them. I tried to change it to display all the flowers with either red or yellow. It either comes back to this or changes to where it displays flowers with just red on checking just red or flowers with just yellow (and forgets red on checking yellow also with red).

```
$('.flowers-wrap,.planets-wrap').delegate('input[type=checkbox]', 'change', function() {
    var $lis = $('.flowers > div'),
        $checked = $('input:checked');
    if ($checked.length) {
        var selector = '';
        $($checked).each(function(index, element) {
            selector += "[data-category~='" + element.id + "']";
            alert(selector);
        });
        $lis.hide();
        $('.flowers > div').filter(selector).show();
    } else {
        $lis.show();
    }
});
```

What I want is `(red or yellow) and (small,med,large) and (mars, venus)`. How to change this fiddle example to make it work how I want it to? Thanks.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

while you are iterating through all checked elements, you don't need to make a selector you can just show using the `element.id` of each checked checkbox. something like this:

```
$('.flowers-wrap,.planets-wrap').delegate('input[type=checkbox]', 'change', function() {
    var $lis = $('.flowers > div'),
        $checked = $('input:checked');  
    if ($checked.length) {  
        $lis.hide(); 
        $($checked).each(function(index, element) {                     
            $("[data-category~='" + element.id + "']").show();                            
        });                                              
    } else {
        $lis.show();
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. This is somewhat I'm looking for, but not exactly. What I want is `(red or yellow) and (small,med,large) and (mars, venus)` This shows red or yellow or small or medium or...

Comment: @SajalGupta do you want to select all reds and yellows simultaneously when you check them? let me know if I understood you correctly

Comment: on clicking red, `red flowers` come. then on clicking yellow, `red and yellow` flowers show. on clicking small, `small red or small yellow` flowers. on clicking medium, `small or medium AND small or medium yellow` come. on clicking mars, `small or medium red flowers on mars AND small or medium yellow flowers on mars` show. its a complicated filter. something like this :  `https://bschool.careers360.com/colleges/list-of-mba-colleges-in-India`

Comment: @SajalGupta `on clicking small, small red or small yellow flowers` are you going to choose randomly between them?

Comment: Yes. User can click on anyone of them in any order. Please see the careers360 link. That filter is exactly what I want. [link](https://bschool.careers360.com/colleges/list-of-mba-colleges‌​-in-India)

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is to change `selector` variable declaration to an empty array instead of an empty string and then iterate over its contents filtering for each item:

```
$('.flowers-wrap,.planets-wrap').delegate('input[type=checkbox]', 'change', function() {
  var $lis = $('.flowers > div'),
      $checked = $('input:checked');    
  if ($checked.length)
  {                         
    var selectors = [];//declare empty array named selectorS
    $($checked).each(function(index, element){                            
      selectors.push("[data-category~='" + element.id + "']");                            
    });                        
    $lis.hide();         
    selectors.forEach(function(selector){//iterate over elements
      $('.flowers > div').filter(selector).show();  
    })

  }
  else
  {
    $lis.show();
  }
});
```

Comment: this is doing exactly what Dij's code is doing. Please check the comment on that answer. Thanks.

Comment: [careers360.com > management > read > mba college in india](https://bschool.careers360.com/colleges/list-of-mba-colleges-in-India)